# Does "accrued great appreciation of his dedication" sound right?

Tags: meaning, expressions, american-english

Here is the sentence, During the 4 year collaboration, we accrued great appreciation of his professionalism.

My question is about 2 words, "accrued" and "of".

First, I never see such usage as "accrue appreciation". Does it sound right to you? The problem is, if this is not right, what should be the right expression to say, accumulated appreciation over a period of time.

Second, I am almost certain, "of" should be "to" so that it should be "we accrued great appreciation to his professionalism".

Please let me know how you think.

Comment: It sounds off to me.  One *gains* appreciation rather than accrues it.  ***Of*** is correct.  One has an appreciation *of* something not to it.

Comment: "...we benefited greatly from his knowledge and professionalism". Sound's strange to me to just have 'professionalism' as a key descriptor. Also, "4(-)year collaboration".

Comment: "...we grew to appreciate his professionalism greatly".

Comment: *For* would also work as a preposition. (*To* would not.) But using *accrue*, while syntactically sound, is awkward at an idiomatic level.